# Identify involving two different permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, permutation-matrices

During my calculations for a proof, I want to find two permutation matrices $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that:

$$P_1 A = A P_2$$

for a given matrix $A$. What can we say about $P_1$ and $P_2$, other than it holds for $P_1=P_2=I$?

For instance, let's take $P_1$ shuffling the rows of the symmetric matrix $A$ as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c\\
b & d & e \\
c & e & f\end{bmatrix}= 
\begin{bmatrix} c & e & f\\
a & b & c \\
b & d & e \end{bmatrix}$$

We can see there is no way to have a $P_2$ shuffling the columns of our original symmetric matrix and have the same result. So in general it is not possible. Are there particular class of matrices $A$ or/and choice of matrices $P_1$ and $P_2$ for which the above equality holds?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you considered the $2 \times 2$ case or the $3 \times 3$ case?

Comment: I have updated my question, thanks.

Comment: After permuting the rows and columns compare the components to get a relationship that the matrix must satisfy. Then substitute to simplify and examine the form it must take. So in your example with $P_1A=AI$ you'll have $a=c$ from the top left component, $d=b$ from the center component and so on.

Comment: Have you considered diagonal matrices?